# Pip dependeny issue while tring to host with AWS beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
awscli 1.32.58 requires botocore==1.34.58, but you have botocore 1.31.85 which is incompatible.
s3transfer 0.10.0 requires botocore<2.0a.0,>=1.33.2, but you have botocore 1.31.85 which is incompatible.

I keep getting this error whisst using thw awscli. I can't manage to find a version that is compatible allaround. Tryied donwgrading and upgrading the dependencies but still not working.

Anyone knows a way to workaround this issue?

I keep getting this error whisst using thw awscli. I can't manage to find a version that is compatible allaround. Tryied donwgrading and upgrading the dependencies but still not working.

Anyone knows a way to workaround this issue?

Comment: why do you need awscli in your project? are you using virtual environment? Put "python" tags and you will get more help